# How do I place an object on a layout screen in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to earn how to control where I place an object when developing android layouts. It seems like a natural way to do this would be to pick a layout like "GridLayout" and then place the object where I want it.

However, every time I choose grid layout and specify a given number of rows and columns, they are always skewed like this

[image]

How do I equalize the cell sizes so I can place the object?

Comment: RelativeLayouts are typically better for general layouts. Do you explicitly need a grid? What is the end result you are trying to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Relative layout to place your object anywhere you want.

Or you can use latest Constraint layout.